# Android Actionbar Tabs, Fragments, and WebViews

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-actionbar

I'm working on an app with Actionbar tabs and the first activity it loads is just a webview. My issue is I can't find where to do

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

I've tried onStart() in the class that inflates the layout with the webview, but that causes the application to crash.
I've tried in the onCreate() of the main class which loads the tabs, but nothing happens when I do that.

The entire project is on my Github.

https://github.com/cr5315/AOKPCBapp

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in `onActivityCreated`, which is called when the fragment's activity has been created and its fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. `onActivityCreated` is often used to do final initialization once these pieces are in place, such as retrieving views or restoring state. Performing these actions in this method will ensure that the call to `findViewById` will not return `null`.

The `Fragment` lifecycle is an important concept to understand. You can read more about it [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle).

Comment: That's where I have it right now but the WebView doesn't load.

Comment: I don't get any messages at all. The app runs fine, the webview just doesn't load.

Comment: OK, you really shouldn't be starting variable names with capital letters. This is in accordance with Java programming standards... it's very confusing.

Comment: Also, your project loads the url in `onCreateView`, not `onActivityCreated`.

Comment: I put a log in the onActivityCreated along with the webview stuff and the log shows up in the logcat, but the webview still doesn't load.

Comment: `onActivityCreated` is *always* called (assuming the `Activity` doesn't loop or terminate itself in `onCreate`), so that doesn't tell me anything. you should post your code or update your project and then i can help you out.

Comment: It doesn't look updated to me. Could you link me to your code?

Comment: https://github.com/cr5315/AOKPCBapp/blob/master/src/com/cr5315/AOKPCB/WebsiteFragment.java

Comment: None of your XML files contain a `<fragment>` tag, which tells me that your fragments getting inflated/attached to the activity along with the rest of the layout.